# Google Calendar Recurring Events not sending BYDAY

Tags: google-calendar-api

Google usually sends me the data in this way:

> ["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=WE"]

As far as I know, it repeats on Wednesdays, but on other occasions, it sends me the data in this way without the BYDAY:

> ["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY"]

Would I have to apply logic myself to calculate the day of the start date? Or is there any way for Google to send it to me correctly within the rule?